# AngularJS $http.get not firing

Tags: angularjs

I have a page that has a datepicker on it. When a date is picked I have a function being called which assigns the new date to a variable and then calls a $http.get.

The variable gets assigned fine as I have this returning to the page but the $http.get fails and I cant see why. The call syntax is fine as I use it in another function and when I look at the Network viewer in IE I can see that its not even being fired.

Any help would be great.
Thanks :-)

The HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="date-picker" class="panel panel-heading" ng-controller="timesheetViewerCtrl">
        <!--<div>
            Choose A Week End Date:
            <select ng-model="selectedWeek" ng-options="val for val in years"> </select>
        </div>-->
        <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Choose a Week End Date:
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                date-disabled="isDateDisabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" ng-change="changeSelect(dt)"
                close-text="Close" /> 
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>{{changeDate}}
    <br>To Check Filter Select any of the following (joining date) from Datepicker.
</pre>
    </div>
```

and the JS

```
angular.module("timesheetApp").controller("timesheetViewerCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.dt = new Date();

    $scope.open = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'starting-day': 1
    };

    $scope.format = 'dd-MM-yyyy';

    $scope.isDateDisabled = function (date, mode) {

        return (mode === 'day' && date.getDay() !== 0);
    };



    $scope.changeSelect = function (dt) {
        $scope.changeDate = moment(dt).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
        $http.get("/api/tblEntries/")
           .then(onUserComplete, onError);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you run this with your browsers dev tools and console open you would see the error. Vineet is right with it being in reference to the missing service reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please inject [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service in your controller declaration like

```
controller("timesheetViewerCtrl", function ($scope, $http)
```

Comment: @DeeSheehan please accept the answer for future uses.